# How to load springboot properties?

Tags: spring-boot, properties, configuration, autowired, postconstruct

I'm trying to load properties once in my springboot application.

Actually, I have created a class to do that :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:parameters.properties", "classpath:iot.properties" })
public class PropertiesHelper {
    @Autowired
    protected Environment env;

    private static Environment properties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        properties = env;
    }

    public static String getProperty(final String propertyName) {
        return properties.getProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

This class work fine but this is not clean code (sonar hate my static variable).

So, how can I load in my springboot application all my properties correctly and only once ?

Comment: 1. Why?
2. Environment may not give you the overridden value of the poroperty. So you may end up with incorrect values.

Comment: You can use

    `@Autowired
    protected Environment env;`

Anywhere you need it, its a singleton so its only loaded once.

Comment: The question is how to write cleanly property singleton ?

Comment: Can you help me please ?

Comment: I think you missing the point here the properties `@Autowired protected Environment env;` is already a clean singleton provided by spring. As you are already using Spring you can inject this. Further you can inject a specific value using `@Value`. I don't know why you are trying to create a singleton from a singleton. Do you need to make a call from a static method to get the property?And if so why?
Seems like you have a design issue here.

Answer (score 0):

```
@PropertySource("classpath:parameters.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:iot.properties")
public class PropertiesHelper {

@Value( "${Value.you.need}" )
private String valueYouNeed;
}
```

parameters.properties

```
Value.you.need=12345
```

Make it something like this, it should be work in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

## An elegant solution

If you just want to eliminate the sonar alarm（sonar hate my static variable）

```
// application.properties
spring.profiles.active=test1010

// IOC config bean container
@Configuration
@Data
public class PropertiesConfig{
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active:preline}")
    private String profiles;
}

//Use
@Autowired
private PropertiesConfig propertiesConfig;

@GetMapping("/getPropertiesConfig")
public String getPropertiesConfig(){
    return propertiesConfig.getProfiles();
}
```

I think the above scheme is a more elegant way~，Do you have a better solution？